# SQL Server 2005 Express: upgrading to SP3 in mixed-mode installations

Tags: sql-server-2005, password

I'm having trouble upgrading SQL Server 2005 Express SP1 to SP3.

The SP1 install uses mixed mode authentication (so there is an `sa` password).

This is the message I get:

```
TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Setup
------------------------------
None of the selected features can be installed or upgraded. Setup cannot proceed since no effective change is being made to the machine. To continue, click Back and then select features to install. To exit SQL Server Setup, click Cancel.

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?LinkID=20476&ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=SQLSetup90&EvtType=28108
------------------------------
BUTTONS: OK
------------------------------
```

The [link](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=9.00.4035.00&EvtSrc=setup.rll&EvtID=SQLSetup90&EvtType=28108) then tells me **To continue you must provide a strong sa password.**

I tried some searching, and [found](http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-setup/9296/Failed-to-upgrade-from-SQL-Server-2000-to-SQL-Server-2005) [something](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/33379217/failed-to-upgrade-from-sq.aspx) [about](http://www.microsoft.com/communities/newsgroups/en-us/default.aspx?dg=microsoft.public.sqlserver.setup&tid=2f82b263-39d0-4a0a-8198-120be1e97281&cat=&lang=&cr=&sloc=&p=1) `BPAClient.dll`, but this batch-file does not fix it:

```
mkdir "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\BPA\BPAClient"
copy "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\BPA\bin\BPAClient.dll" "%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\BPA\BPAClient\"
```

I also tried [this](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=41775.0), but that didn't help either (probably because the services had been started at least once before trying the update).

So I think the clue is the `strong` in the link above.
Am I on the right track?
<strike>Where do I find more information on the `strongness` of an sa password?</strike>
Duh - that was in the above link. Just didn't read well enough.
So I changed the sa password to something strong (Upper and lower case letters, special signs, at least 6 characters).
Rebooted, restarted SP3 install: still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved; the last [link about SBS installation guide](http://forum.avast.com/index.php?topic=41775.0) I mentioned above also had this somewhere in the middle:

> Didn't think about it until I downlaoded the SP3 and ran it that it is the FULL install with SP3. DUH!

So this is how I upgraded from SQL Server Express 2005 SP1 to SP3:

1. Uninstall SQL Server Express 2005 SP1
2. Install the SQL Server Express 2005 SP3 (which now acts as a new install)

Simple but effective :-)

--jeroen